# Duplicating Carrierwave images makes them darker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, duplicates, activeadmin, carrierwave

I have an `Event` model that has many `photographs`. I have an image uploader mounted to the Photographs attribute, and regular uploads and everything is working fine.

However, when I try and duplicate an event, recreating a new photograph object for the new event, the new image is darker than the original, and if I duplicate the duplicate event, it gets darker still.

I have played around with it, but have no solution.

My Uploader code:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::Processing::RMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/carrierwave"
  end

  process :colorspace => :rgb

  # Remove EXIF data
  process :strip

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [640, 640]
  end

  version :preview_thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [600, 600]
  end

  version :wine_thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [160, 440]
  end

  version :logo_thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [90, 90]
  end
end
```

And my duplcation code (in Active Admin):

```
member_action :create_duplicate_event, method: :post do
  old_event = Event.find(params[:id])
  photograph_urls = old_event.photographs.map(&:image_url)
  attributes = old_event.attributes.except("photographs", "id")

  new_photos = []
  photograph_urls.each do |photo|
    new_photo = Photograph.new({
      remote_image_url: photo
    })

    if new_photo.save
      new_photos << new_photo
    end
  end
  @event = Event.new(attributes)
  @event.photograph_ids = new_photos.map(&:id)

  render "/admin/events/_events_form/"
end
```

The :rgb tag was an attempt to fix. But no luck.

Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of playing around and searching I managed to fix this problem.

First, you need to download the .icc color profiles, which can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/iccprofiles/iccprofiles_win.html). It says for windows but they seemed to work for me on my Mac.

Once you have put the `.icc` files into a `/lib/color_profiles` directory, add the following code to your uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  process :convert_image_from_cmyk_to_rgb

  #versions, and any other uploader code go here

  def convert_image_from_cmyk_to_rgb
    manipulate! do |image|
      if image.colorspace == Magick::CMYKColorspace
        image.strip!
        image.add_profile("#{Rails.root}/lib/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc")
        image.colorspace == Magick::SRGBColorspace
        image.add_profile("#{Rails.root}/lib/sRGB.icc")
      end
      image
    end
  end
end
```

This converts CMYK images to RGB, and keeps the profiles keeping nice, while keeping RGB images as they were, and not ruining them.

I hope this helps someone in the future, and saves them the hours I spent working this out.